# Trying to get CUDA 7.5 to work with GCC 5.x

Tags: c++, cuda, gcc5

So, if you try to use nvcc when the system GCC is version 5 and up, you get an "unsupported version" error. But - I've heard people report that they've just commented this out and that CUDA 7.5 "works for them" with GCC 5.x .

When I do the same, however (the check is in `$CUDA_DIR/host_config.h`), and compile something, I get the following errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/include/mwaitxintrin.h(36): error: identifier "__builtin_ia32_monitorx" is undefined
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/include/mwaitxintrin.h(42): error: identifier "__builtin_ia32_mwaitx" is undefined
```

and a bunch of others, but those may be dependent on these. Now, these are MMX-related intrinsics for X86 architectures. I don't use them directly, so I'm guessing they're opted-in somehow. Perhaps this can be avoided?

Is there a way to overcome these errors and actually get GCC 5 to coexist with CUDA 7.5? And for code to build and run?

**Notes:**

- I've read a suggestion to use `-D__STRICT_ANSI__`. I have, and it doesn't seem to help.
- I'm on Fedora 22 in case it matters.

Comment: Is there a concrete question here somewhere?

Comment: @talonmies: Sorry, thought it was obvious. See edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's essentially futile to try to get GCC 5.x to work with CUDA 7.5 - there are some (or many?) incompatiblity issues which you simply can't resolve. Instead, just upgrade to CUDA 8.0 which has become available since this question was asked.

Answer (score 3):

I think a `-D_MWAITXINTRIN_H_INCLUDED` option should fix the issue. Actually I employed a slightly different approach, commenting out the `#include <mwaitxintrin.h>` line in `x86intrin.h`, and successfully built TensorFlow with CUDA 7.5 and GCC 5.2.1.

**UPDATE**

For the latest version of TensorFlow (v0.8.0), simply choose to use gcc 4.x when invoking the `configure` script.

Comment: TensorFlow now allows you to manually specify which gcc to use. It is recommended to use gcc 4.x instead of gcc 5.x with hacks.

Comment: You should delete the outdated part of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider installing and temporary selecting an older version of the `gcc`:

```
apt-get install gcc-4.8
```

Then update your alternatives:

```
update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 10
```

After compiling TensorFlow you can use previous version of `gcc` calling above command with proper path to `/usr/bin/gcc-5.x`.